# Training Cartpole using policy gradient and gradient tape of tensorflow is not converging

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to train the cartpole environment using policy gradients algorithm by using tensorflow and keras.

I want to train using the GradientTape method of tensorflow. I have been trying for a long time, but still it hasn't converged.

I already solved it without using GradientTape and it worked fine. The same loss function and discounted rewards method is being used, still it doesn't converge.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np
import keras.backend as K
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class PolicyGradientModel(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, num_actions):
        super().__init__()
        self.hidden1 = layers.Dense(24, activation='relu')
        self.hidden2 = layers.Dense(120, activation='relu')
        self.out = layers.Dense(num_actions, activation='softmax')

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.hidden1(inputs)
        x = self.hidden2(x)
        return self.out(x)

    def action_prob(self, state):
        prob = self.predict(np.expand_dims(state, axis=0))
        return prob[0]

    def action(self, state):
        prob = self.action_prob(state)
        action = np.random.choice(len(prob), p=prob)
        return action

def calculate_discount_rewards(rewards, gamma = 0.99, standardize = False, normalize = False):
    len_episodes = len(rewards)
    discount_factors = np.power(0.99, np.arange(1, len_episodes + 1, 1))
    
    discount_rewards = discount_factors * rewards
    
    if standardize:
        discount_rewards = (discount_rewards - np.mean(discount_rewards)) / (np.std(discount_rewards) + 1e-10)
        
    if normalize:
        discount_rewards = discount_rewards / np.max(discount_rewards)
        
    return discount_rewards


def log_policy_loss(discount_rewards, action_prob_):
    return -K.sum(discount_rewards[:, np.newaxis] * K.log(action_prob_))

def train_step(model, optimizer, states, actions, rewards):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        one_hot_actions = tf.one_hot(actions, 2)
        logits = model(states)
        action_prob_ = tf.reduce_sum(one_hot_actions * logits, axis = 1)
        loss = log_policy_loss(rewards, action_prob_)
    grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

def train(model, env, optimizer):
    rewards_history = []
    for episode in range(1000):
        state = env.reset()
        episode_rewards = []
        states = []
        actions = []
        done = False
        rewards_till = 0
        while not done:
            env.render()
            action = model.action(state)
            next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
            states.append(state)
            actions.append(action)
            rewards_till += reward
            episode_rewards.append(rewards_till)
            state = next_state
        rewards_history.append(sum(episode_rewards))
        discounted_episode_rewards = calculate_discount_rewards(episode_rewards, normalize = True)
        train_step(model, optimizer, np.vstack(states), np.array(actions),discounted_episode_rewards)
        if episode % 100 == 0:
            print(f'Episode no. {episode} with reward of {episode_rewards[-1]}')

    plt.plot(np.arange(len(rewards_history)), rewards_history)
    plt.show()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import gym
    env = gym.make('CartPole-v1')
    model = PolicyGradientModel(env.action_space.n)
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
    train(model, env, optimizer)
    model.save('cartpole-policy-gradient-tape', save_format = 'tf')
```